# What is a "trigger reaction"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What kind of reaction is a "trigger reaction"? Is it a immediate and instant reaction?

> The context is added:
>
> The available space is too confined,rendering any such meeting of
>   gazes ‘unbearable’, but somehow the weight of that which haunts the
>   scene makes it all the more so. A trigger reaction to a prevalent
>   sense of both unease and not-quiteknowing- what-to-think which to some
>   extent determines the route you end up taking through the grid, and
>   which is surely replicated over and over.

Comment: Context please.  Where did you see this used, and can you provide a complete sentence or ideally paragraph?

Comment: @Max Williams  the context is added.

Comment: I would say it's what happens when the butterfly flaps it's wings.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of just a "trigger reaction" being used like this. I think you could be speaking of one of two things:

- Hair-trigger reaction

> 1:   immediately responsive to the slightest stimulus (*a hair–trigger temper*)

Source: [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hair%E2%80%93trigger)

- To trigger (a reaction)

> to cause someone to do or say something (*The report has triggered a fierce response from the governor.*)

Source: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trigger_1)

Answer (score 0):

It refers to a prompt and often strong reaction to something said or done:

to ***[trigger](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trigger_1) a reaction***:

> - to cause someone to do or say something:
>
>   - ***trigger a response/reaction***: The report has triggered a fierce response from the governor.

(MacMillan Dictionary)